# Android AQuery loading image by ImageView, not by ImageView ID

Tags: android

I am facing a problem with loading image, using AQuery.

I saw several example code like this

```
aq.id(R.id.imageView).image(url, false, false);
```

it works fine, but my task is to use imageview itself, like

```
(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

not by imageview id, which is

```
R.id.imageView.
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: the question is too ambiguous.. could you please make it clear?

Comment: Where you define ImageView itself. And where you want to display an Image?. Describe more

Comment: @peterLEE you are able to access R.id.imageView any where in the activity,